# Python Tkinter- Clear a text box every time it is clicked and displaying with digit group separator

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, textbox

I am writing a simple app to calculate some values according to entered value by user. I almost accomplished it!
Now I want to know:
1. How can I clear my `txtFixedIncome` text box every time I click on it?
2. How can it be implemented to display the content of `txtFixedIncome` text box with thousands separator (digit group separator)? i.e. displaying `27659` as `27,659`.

```
import tkinter
mainForm = tkinter.Tk()
mainForm.title('Shahr Fixed Income Fund')
def btnCalculatePressed():
    txtCalculationResult.delete('1.0', 'end')
    #txtCalculationResult.insert(tkinter.INSERT, "Button was pressed")
    #txtCalculationResult.pack()
    yourIncomePortion = txtFixedIncome.get('1.0', 'end')
    print(yourIncomePortion)
    txtCalculationResult.insert(tkinter.INSERT, yourIncomePortion)
btnCalculate = tkinter.Button(mainForm , text = "Calculate", command= btnCalculatePressed)
txtCalculationResult = tkinter.Text(mainForm )
txtCalculationResult.insert(tkinter.INSERT, "CalculationResults")
txtFixedIncome = tkinter.Text(mainForm, height = 1, width = 30 )
txtFixedIncome.insert(tkinter.INSERT, "your income portion")

txtFixedIncome.pack();
txtCalculationResult.pack()
btnCalculate.pack() 

mainForm.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your second question is unclear

Comment: i.e. displaying `27659` as `27,659`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution of first question:

[`bind`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) focus in and focus out of your widget. Like:

```
txtFixedIncome.bind("<FocusIn>",lambda _:txtFixedIncome.delete('1.0', 'end'))
txtFixedIncome.bind("<FocusOut>",lambda _:txtFixedIncome.insert("1.0","your income portion" if str(txtFixedIncome.get("1.0","end")) == "\n" else ""))
```

This will erase all data in entry when focused out and enter information data when focused in.

---

#### Solution of second question:

You can make a function to update your values and format them like:

```
def updat(text):
    try:txtCalculationResult.insert(tkinter.INSERT,"{:,.0f}".format(float(text)))
    except:txtCalculationResult.insert(tkinter.INSERT,"CalculationResults")
```

As:

```
>>> "{:,.0f}".format(23442)
'23,442'
>>>
```

---

#### Full code:

Here is a full example code that shows the behavior you are expecting:

```
import tkinter
mainForm = tkinter.Tk()
mainForm.title('Shahr Fixed Income Fund')
def updat(text):
    try:txtCalculationResult.insert(tkinter.INSERT,"{:,.0f}".format(float(text)))
    except:txtCalculationResult.insert(tkinter.INSERT,"CalculationResults")
def btnCalculatePressed():
    txtCalculationResult.delete('1.0', 'end')
    yourIncomePortion = txtFixedIncome.get('1.0', 'end')
    updat(yourIncomePortion)
btnCalculate = tkinter.Button(mainForm , text = "Calculate", command= btnCalculatePressed)
txtCalculationResult = tkinter.Text(mainForm)
txtCalculationResult.insert(tkinter.INSERT, "CalculationResults")
txtFixedIncome = tkinter.Text(mainForm, height = 1, width = 30 )
txtFixedIncome.insert(tkinter.INSERT, "your income portion")

txtFixedIncome.bind("<FocusIn>",lambda _:txtFixedIncome.delete('1.0', 'end'))
txtFixedIncome.bind("<FocusOut>",lambda _:txtFixedIncome.insert("1.0","your income portion" if str(txtFixedIncome.get("1.0","end")) == "\n" else ""))

txtFixedIncome.pack();
txtCalculationResult.pack()
btnCalculate.pack() 

mainForm.mainloop()
```

---

#### Format during typing:

If you want to format the string during typing as you commented then use the following code:

```
import tkinter
mainForm = tkinter.Tk()
mainForm.title('Shahr Fixed Income Fund')
def updat(text):
    try:txtCalculationResult.insert(tkinter.INSERT,"{:,.0f}".format(float(text.replace(",",""))))
    except:txtCalculationResult.insert(tkinter.INSERT,"CalculationResults")
def btnCalculatePressed():
    txtCalculationResult.delete('1.0', 'end')
    yourIncomePortion = txtFixedIncome.get('1.0', 'end')
    updat(yourIncomePortion)
btnCalculate = tkinter.Button(mainForm , text = "Calculate", command= btnCalculatePressed)
txtCalculationResult = tkinter.Text(mainForm)
txtCalculationResult.insert(tkinter.INSERT, "CalculationResults")
txtFixedIncome = tkinter.Text(mainForm, height = 1, width = 30 )
txtFixedIncome.insert(tkinter.INSERT, "your income portion")
def updat2():
    text = txtFixedIncome.get("1.0","end")
    txtFixedIncome.delete("1.0","end")
    try:
        txtFixedIncome.insert(tkinter.INSERT,"{:,.0f}".format(float(text.replace(",",""))))
    except:
        txtFixedIncome.insert(tkinter.INSERT,text[:-1])
txtFixedIncome.bind("<FocusIn>",lambda _:txtFixedIncome.delete('1.0', 'end'))
txtFixedIncome.bind("<FocusOut>",lambda _:txtFixedIncome.insert("1.0","your income portion" if str(txtFixedIncome.get("1.0","end")) == "\n" else ""))
txtFixedIncome.bind("<Key>",lambda _:mainForm.after(50,updat2))

txtFixedIncome.pack();
txtCalculationResult.pack()
btnCalculate.pack() 

mainForm.mainloop()
```

Comment: Works fine. Thanks. It is better to add thousands separator when user is typing than after pressing button. Is there any way to add thousands separator in typing time?

Comment: binding to `<FocusIn>` and `<FocusOut>` will bind to more than just a click. The OP specifically asked about a click.

Comment: @BryanOakley I can't understand what you are trying to say. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @BlackThunder: `<FocusIn>` will trigger on clicks, but it may also trigger if you press the tab key or shift-tab key when the focus is on a widget just before or after the entry, or if you click on some other application and then click back to this application.

Comment: @BryanOakley I doesn't see it happening.

Comment: @BlackThunder: I don't know what you're doing so I can't explain it. _By definition_, `<FocusIn>` triggers when the widget gets the focus. There are several ways in which a widget can get the focus, and not all of them are mouse clicks.

Comment: @BryanOakley I know that click can be binded using `<Button-1>` but I think the options I have used are more better.